# Accessing dynamically allocated structure inside a function

Tags: c, function, struct

In the below code, I want to access the structure element that is dynamically allocated inside a function. I have declared structure globally, but allocated inside fun1(). I cannot access the structure element after receiving the structure elements. Kindly help me where I have gone wrong. This works fine if it is in single function. Thanks in advance.

```
struct s1
{
    int a;
    char b[10];
} *s2;

int val;
void main()
{
    fun1();
    fun2();

    printf("\n Element a %d",(s1->a));
}

fun1()
{
    struct s1 *s2=malloc(sizefof(struct s1)*val);
    recv(fd,(void)&s2,sizeof(struct s1),0);
}

fun2()
{
    printf("\n Element a %d",(s1->a));
}
```

Comment: Describe in greater detail what exactly are you having problems with.

Comment: `recv(fd,(void)&s2,sizeof(struct s1),0);
}` is the `(void)` cast inteneded, it should not compile.

Comment: Here I have used only small chunks of code. The recv() function works fine. The same code works fine if I am using in a single function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems I can see, assuming that `int val;` was initialized and it's value is reasonable

1. You don't check for the return value of `malloc`, it's very unlikely that this is the problem, but that also depends on the value of `val`.
2. You pass the address of the pointer to `recv`.
3. `fun2()` makes no sense at all, the code shouldn't even compile.
4. You redeclare `s2` in `fun1()`, which doesn't seem to be what you want, since you have initially declared `s2` global.
5. The `printf()` statement in `main()` is also broken.

**Note**: in 4 and 5, you should notice that `s1` is the name of the struct, which was a very bad choice and pretty much the first source for your confusion.

So `fun1()` should be re-wirtten

```
fun1()
{
    s2 = malloc(sizefof(*s1) * val);
    if (s2 != NULL)
        recv(fd, s2, val * sizeof(*s2), 0);
}
```

and `fun2()`

```
fun1()
{
    if (s2 != NULL)
        printf("\n Element a %d", s2->a);
}
```

Comment: I have assigned value to val in fun1() but forget to include in this code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of confusion here.

Something like this might be what you're after:

```
struct s1
{
    int a;
    char b[10];
};

struct s1 * fun1(int val)
{
    struct s1 *s = malloc(val * sizeof *s);
    if(s != NULL)
      recv(fd, s, val * sizeof *s, 0);
    return s;
}

void fun2(struct s1 *ptr)
{
    printf("First element's a %d", ptr[0].a);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct s1 *data = fun1(100);
    fun2(data);

    printf("First element's a is %d", data[0].a);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `recv()` can fail too, and that should be checked. It should, also, perhaps be a `read()`?

Basically I removed the global variables, and fixed basic errors in allocation and pointer usage.